# What's the command to open the Unity Dash?

Tags: unity, command-line, launcher, unity-dash, shortcuts

I would like to know the command (from the Terminal) which opens the Unity dash, the reason being I want to create a desktop icon that starts the dash instead of the 'Windows Key' for keyboard-free use of the computer (I miss the old Ubuntu-Tweak effect where putting your mouse to the corner of the desktop would reveal Expo or Scale effects - by the way, is it possible to get it back?)

Making a launcher (Application, Name, Command, Comment, etc) I tried the commands 'Unity', 'Dash' and other things, but I didn't manage to get it to work.

I am using version 12.04

Answer (score 7):

Install the package `xdotool` (`sudo apt-get install xdotool`) and use

```
xdotool key super
```

Answer (score 7):

- This is quite simple using *xdotool* -- a small command-line utility which automates keyboard and mouse clicks/movements; install it with `sudo apt-get install xdotool`
- In your `.desktop` shortcut, simply set the `Exec` line as:

  ```
  Exec=xdotool key --clearmodifiers Super
  ```