# Hotkey to press 'Search your computer' button

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

[image]

I would like to bind my (windows key / super key) to open the 'Search your computer' button. 
In order to bind it, I believe i need to know the terminal command to open it first. So my question how do I launch 'Search your computer' from the terminal?

I am using ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: which version of Ubuntu are you using? Current version use the Gnome desktop which doesn't include such a feature but instead pressing the left Super (Windows) key presents a Type to Search dialogue. https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/search-your-computer-button/6783/8 Your graphic suggests and earlier version.

Comment: Is this similar to what Alt+F2 does now?

Comment: I don't know. Alt+F2 doesn't do anything for me.

Answer (score 0):

The Super key is supposed to open this menu by default, I don't know why this is not the case for you.

While I don't know how you can open the "Search your computer" menu, it is possible to open the "Search applications" menu, which might be enough in your case.

You can do this using *xdotool* (as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/192295/386483)):

- Install it with `sudo apt-get install xdotool`
- Create a new shortcut with `xdotool key --clearmodifiers Super+a` and assign it to the key combination you want